# Почему выбивает на указанной строке?

Tags: c++, указатели, динамические-массивы

Поясните мне мою ошибку в данной функции на выделение памяти.
Как только доходит до строчки `numb[i] = new char[50];` - сразу ошибка и в отладчике пишет что чтение памяти невозможно.
`**cont i` `**numb` абсолютно две идентичные переменные (в дальнейшем это должна быть телефонная книга). Один массив отвечает за имена, второй за номера

```
void Memory(char**&cont, char**&numb, int q) 
{
    cont = new char*[q];
    for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
    {
        cont[i] = new char[50];
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
    {
        numb[i] = new char[50];
    }
}
```

Comment: *"абсолютно две идентичные функции"* -- какие такие функции?

Comment: char**& тут точно всё нормально?..

Comment: @PinkTux ой, переменные

Comment: @pavel da, tam vse normal'no

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Возможно, что для указателя `numb` вы забыли выделить память, как, например

```
numb = new char*[q];
```

Ваша функция могла бы выглядеть следующим лобразом

```
void Memory( char ** &cont, char ** &numb, int q ) 
{
    cont = new char *[q];
    for ( int i = 0; i < q; i++ )
    {
        cont[i] = new char[50];
    }

    numb = new char *[q];
    for (int i = 0; i < q; i++)
    {
        numb[i] = new char[50];
    }
}
```

Хотя интерфейс этой функции очень неясный. Например, могут ли указатели, переданные в функцию, уже указывать на выделенную ранее память? То есть должен ли в начале вызываться оператор `delete` для этих указателей.

В функции используются непонятные "магические числа".

Лучше функцию написать таким образом. чтобы она имела дело только с одним указателем, и для каждого указателя вызывать ее отдельно.